# Why file isn't found in qt make even though file is existed

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I want to build executable for open source repositoruy [FFmpegGUI](https://github.com/RomanSichkaruk/FFmpegGUI). I'm completely new to C++ (don't know code and just Googling it since 2 days to make build work). After lots of hours I managed to somehow fix ffmpeg issue and make ./configure work.

Now I'm stuck at `make` command which is giving about file existence issue. Trust me I've Googled and searched on Stack Overflow for similar error but surprisingly I couldn't found any similar issue. (Maybe no one got this error or maybe I'm just too noob). The error code is as following...

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic src/filtersList.ui -o ui_filtersList.h
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic src/filtersWidget.ui -o ui_filtersWidget.h
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic src/inspectionWidget.ui -o ui_inspectionWidget.h
g++ -c -pipe -fpermissive -std=c++0x -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o connectivity.o src/connectivity.cpp
In file included from src/filter.h:34,
                 from src/pad.h:47,
                 from src/connectivity.cpp:26:
src/filtersWidget.h:28:10: fatal error: filter.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include <filter.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:568: connectivity.o] Error 1
```

I don't know what I did wrong but anyway no matter what I do. I always get above error when I run `make` command.

Please watch this [Video GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uimg6.jpg) to check if I did anything wrong or not.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to be a complete answer, but an explanation is too long for a comment.

It looks like connectivity.cpp includes pad.h, and pad.h includes filter.h. I bet if you look at both of those, the include looks something like:

```
#include "pad.h"
#include "filter.h"
```

But then filter.h has:

```
#include <filter.h>
```

This is confusing, but how the compiler finds include files varies if you use <> vs. "". Using "" it looks relative from the location of the file doing the include. Using <>, it uses the include file search path, which is modified by -I options on the g++ command line. You can see a bunch of -I options if you scroll over in the g++ line you posted.

Is there another filter.h somewhere? I didn't see -I ./src in the g++ line.

It would be very weird for filter.h to include another filter.h. That's kind of scary.

Comment: I've looked for another ``filter.h`` but there wasn't any other include. I guess it's because I've just setup my linux and since I don't know anything about linux and C++, I guess I've messed up environment setting. Else i dont think readymade repository should throw any errors. Thanks for your help though. I don't know what should I do anymore.